# Designing vectors Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, photoshop

I am currently trying to design the views for my iOS application, I am using Photoshop CS6 for making mockups for my design, and how they should look on the application. Right now I am doing a resolution  for iPhone 5S 640 x 1136 px

Although I wish to use the new feature with vector images in Xcode 6, which resolution should I design in now? Also what is the actual size of a @1x image, is it for the iPhone 3? Or...?

Comment: Alright, but I am still confused about the sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Photoshop is a pixel based software while Illustrator is a vector based software. So if your using Photoshop, you wouldn't even be able to save it into a vector format.

In terms of resolution, by using Illustrator and creating a vector image, resolution doesn't matter at all (you can make it as big or small as you want and it will still be crystal clear)

Anyways, here is the link: https://www.createful.com/2014/using-vector-pdf-icons-xcode-6/

If you need any clarification/questions, just ask!

Comment: Lets say I have a logo I want to add to the design, does it not matter Which size it is? If I export it as a vector?

Comment: Was the logo designed in Photoshop?

Comment: I have no idea, it's downloaded in a PNG file from the internet

Comment: Open the file in Illustrator and do a live trace / image trace. Then save it as a PDF.

Comment: Did u get it or still need help?

Comment: Hi Nick, I am still somehow confused about sizing. So lets say I have a 300x200 logo. And I import to xCode as a PDF, and use it in a storyboard, and resize it to 150x100, would that work? And would it then auto resize for different devices?

Comment: I'm not a pro at auto layout so I don't exactly know. However so long as the logo is a vector, you will able to scale it to whatever resolution you want without and still keep all the detail.

Comment: Alright, do you know what res and iPhone device the storyboard is?

Comment: Like if I use a image in storyboard, does it use 1x or 2x

Comment: You can make the storyboard what ever size you want (if you want it optimized for a certain device you can do that). If you put an image in a storyboard it can be scaled to whatever size you want....x1 and x2 don't really exist for vectors since they are universal.